# Why is Chrome using 1.5 CPU cores even though I just started my computer and only opened Chrome (didn't go on any website yet)?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu

I just started my computer. I opened Chrome but didn't go on any website yet. However,  Chrome is continuously using 1.5 CPU cores, even after I waited >10 minutes after the Chrome launch. Why?

Demo:

[image]

The task manager of Chrome only shows "Browser" as using most of the CPU. Extensions use <5% of CPU.

Windows Task Manager details:

[image]

Chrome was continuously using 1.5 CPU cores even before I opened the Chrome Task Manager.

Google Chrome is up to date: Version 92.0.45 15.107 (Official Build) (64-bit). I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Updating to Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) didn't fix the issue.

Comment: According to the Chrome developer guide, that’s usage of a single core, as for the reason it’s so high is due to your extensive list of extensions.  It’s also due to the fact Chrome is a resource hog.

Comment: If 150 is of a single core, then what is it out of (if not a percent)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The task manager of Chrome tells you exactly why. Each extension you run is being run in a separate process too and given the large scroll bar, it shows you have a lot of extensions.

The browser in Google Chrome's taskmanager is the main process. In order for your browser to work, it has to communicate with the rest of the system. So at Chrome launch, all plugins are loaded, and thus the CPU power for the browser process is high.

Answer (score 4):

The following comment gave the correct, albeit tedious  answer:

> You will want to **disable the extensions one by one until it drops to find out what extension is the cause here**. For example, it could be that one extension was updated and now contains a crypto miner. – [LPChip](https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip)[12 hours](https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl/1667178#comment2555484_1666970)

This other comment gives a solution to make it less tedious to check:

> Since you have a lot of extensions, you may want to not do them 1 by 1, but instead do a **binary search**, where you would turn off half. If the problem happens again, shut off half of what is left. If it's not, try the other half instead. Repeat until you're down to a manageable number of extensions. Also, **as a sanity check, you may want to create a new profile, with no extensions, and have CHrome create an icon for it on your Desktop**. Close Chrome, and open just that profile, and make sure the problem recurs. That way it's clear it's an extension causing the problem. – [trlkly](https://superuser.com/users/163497/trlkly) [11 hours ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1666969/why-is-chrome-using-1-5-cpu-cores-even-though-i-just-started-my-computer-and-onl/1667178#comment2555516_1666970)

In my case, the CPU usage came  from the Google Chrome extension https://www.grammarly.com/:

[image]

Note that to find which Google Chrome extension causing the issue, one has to restart Google Chrome after disabling the extension (because disabling the extension without restarting Google Chrome doesn't guarantee that the CPU usage will decrease: in my case it didn't, and I had to restart Google Chrome for CPU usage to decrease).